# When do faithfully semiinjective complexes exist?

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, injective-modules

Question:

> For which (perhaps noncommutative but always unital and associative) rings $R$ do faithfully semiinjective complexes of right or left $R$-modules exist?

Hopefully the answer is: "for all". If this is unknown in general, I'll settle for asking:

> Do such things exist for $R=\Bbb Z$?

This might be really trivial but I have found nothing in the literature. If I just haven't looked hard enough somehow, please let me know of a good source. This is possibly a classical but obscure piece of homological algebra. Bonus points if you can show that / can reference to a proof that it is the case we can always find *faithfully* semiinjective resolutions of arbitrary complexes (I have no idea if this is true).

---

I should define my terms:

A complex of (left or right) $R$-modules, $E$, is semiinjective if the Hom-*complex* functor $\mathsf{Hom}_R(-,E)$ maps injective quasiisomorphisms of complexes to surjective quasiisomorphisms of complexes.

With some labour (namely relying on a demonstration that "good" semiinjective resolutions exist) it can be shown that this is equivalent to saying a number of things, e.g. $E$ is semiinjective only if (and, trivially, if) every object of $E$ is injective and $\mathsf{Hom}_R(-,E)$ preserves *all* quasiisomorphisms.

When I ask for $E$ to be "faithfully semiinjective", I mean that $\mathsf{Hom}_R(-,E)$ is a faithfully exact functor from (the opposite category of) complexes of $R$-modules to Abelian groups *and* that if $\mathsf{Hom}_R(\alpha,E)$ is a quasiisomorphism of the complexes $\mathsf{Hom}_R(M,E)\simeq\mathsf{Hom}_R(N,E)$ then $\alpha$ itself must be a quasiisomorphism.

For $R=\Bbb Z$, the complex $E$ which is just $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ concentrated in degree zero will meet the "faithfully exact" criterion but I am not at all sure if it will meet the "preserves quasiisomorphisms" criterion. By a mapping cone argument, it is equivalent to say that $\mathsf{Hom}_R(M,E)$ is acylic if *and only if* $M$ is acylic; in other words, if for all $n\in\Bbb Z$ we have that every chain map $M\to E[n]$ is nullhomotopic, then $M$ must be acyclic / exact.

---

**Motivation**: page $32$ (pdf page $54$) of [this text](https://www.math.ttu.edu/%7Elchriste/download/918-final.pdf) makes some deductions that I feel  need more justification.

In particular, the claim of theorem $3.4.5$ that $(i)$ will imply $(ii)$ seems to me to be only immediate **if** one assumes such a nice faithfully semiinjective complex $E$ exists (otherwise it is nonsense to appeal to that adjointness argument since you'd have nothing to apply it to!).

To keep it self-contained, that claim is the claim that any semiflat complex $F$ (e.g. a semiprojective complex) must have flat objects and must have that $-\otimes_R F$ preserves quasiisomorphisms. For these authors, semiflatness of a complex means that $-\otimes_R F$ maps injective quasiisomorphisms to injective quasiisomorphisms.
They also rely on existence of such an $E$ to make the important claim that bounded below complexes of flat modules are semiflat. I would really like this to be actually true, but to argue it we do need this magic $E$ (we even only need a magic complex of Abelian groups).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it isn't that hard. We can do better and always find faithfully injective *modules* (I'm certain this is written down somewhere but I'm a "noob" and (i) didn't already know it and (ii) wouldn't know where to look).

Fix $R$. Say we care about left modules; then let $E$ be an injective container of $\bigoplus_{I\text{ is a right ideal}}R/I$. I omit "left,right" adjectives from now on. It is easy to argue any nonzero module admits a nonzero morphism to $E$, so by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/271414) formalism we know $\mathsf{Hom}_R(-,E)$ is faithfully exact as a functor from $R$-modules to Abelian groups.

Because exactness of complexes holds iff. it holds degreewise, it follows $\mathsf{Hom}_R(-,E)$ is faithfully exact as a functor from $R$-complexes to $R$-complexes, where $E$ is viewed as a complex concentrated in degree zero. I want to show that if $M$ is a complex such that $\mathsf{Hom}_R(M,E)$ is exact, then $M$ is also exact.

Since $E$ has only one component, as a complex, the nullhomotopy condition boils down to this:

> If $f:M_n\to E$ vanishes on the boundaries $B_n$ then $f$ factors through $d_n:M_n\to M_{n-1}$.

In other words, $\mathsf{Hom}_R(M_{n-1}, E)\to\mathsf{Hom}_R(M_n, E)\to\mathsf{Hom}_R(B_n, E)$ is an exact sequence (of Abelian groups). That implies $B_n\to M_n\to M_{n-1}$ is exact which just means $H_n(M)=0$. $n$ is arbitrary, so we are done.